# Woocommerce - set a minimum order value per category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want customers to get an error message (at the cart and checkout page) and block their checkout when they did not order more than €100 for each product category in their cart.

In my shop I carry 6 brands which are seperated in product categories (so I only have 6 product categories). So if a customer has products of brand A in its cart he should have at least €100 worth of that brand in his cart to allow the order to be completed. If the cart contains multiple brands then the customer should order at least €100 of each brand in his cart.

The €100 minimum is generic for all brands (product categories), so there is no need to set specific minimums for specific categories. All brands have the same minimum. 
EUROS are my store currency.

And last, but not least, I want this rule to be disabled when the customer applies the coupon with this code: NOMOQ

I have this code to set a general minimum order and allow it to be disabled with the coupon:

```
    /**
 * Give the site a minimum order amount that can be avoided by using a coupon code
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function minimum_order_amount() {

    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 100;

    // No minimum purchase if a specific coupon code is used
    if ( WC()->cart->has_discount( 'nomoq' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) {
        $message = sprintf(
            'You must order at least a total of %s (excluding shipping and VAT) of one brand or a combination of brands. <a title="Find out more!" href="%s" target="_blank">Find out more!</a>',
            wc_price( $minimum ),
            site_url( '/ordering/#moq' )
        );

        if ( is_cart() ) {
            wc_print_notice( $message, 'error' );
        } else {
            wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

---

Who can help me modify this code to fit my needs? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

// Set a max number of products from specific category before checking out

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_max_campioni' );
function spyr_set_max_campioni() {
// Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
global $woocommerce, $product;
$cart_num_products = 0;
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) {
// See if any product is from the campioni category or not
if ( has_term( 'campioni', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] )) {
$cart_num_products++;
}
}
wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'You can buy a maximum of 3 samples.'
Currently there are in the cart:% s. ',
$cart_num_products
'error' );
}
}
}
```

And, You can also check this link 
it's helpful

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/minmax-quantities/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/minimum-purchase-for-woocommerce/screenshots

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-incremental-product-quantities/screenshots/